# Selenium Webdriver with C# Is there a way to Scroll the Mouse wheel?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, nunit, mstest

While using Selenium Webdriver with C# Is there a way to Scroll the Mouse wheel over a Hover Menu?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42645027/how-to-scroll-down-in-dropdown-window-in-selenium-webdriver?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, @Dazed I was, in fact, trying to find out a solution for "Hover Menu" scrolling, to see the menu, first you need to place the mouse cursor on a specific element than when the hover menu appears  you will have to scroll the "Mouse Wheel" as otherwise if you move the mouse the hover menu will disappear

Comment: Do you have a link?